# HTML Quickform2 not working

Tags: html, class, tags, pear, quickform

I am trying to use the PEAR HTML_Quickform2 on XAMPP but it doesn't seem to work. I downloaded the Quickform package and I am following the tutorial but the form doesn't seem to come up. Could anyone give me a clue as to what I'm doing wrong and what I should do? I am using Windows 8.